# How to control flash in camera2 api?

Tags: android, android-camera2, camera2

I am using https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic project to create my own app, But when I added the code to control flash(on, off, auto).

> ```
> private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
>     if (mFlashSupported) {
>
>         if(FLASH_STATUS == 0) {
>             requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
>                     CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
>         }
>         else if(FLASH_STATUS == 1){
>             requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
>                     CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
>         }else if (FLASH_STATUS == 2){
>             requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
>                     CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

It is behaving differently on different devices. Is there any solution which will behave consistant on every device?

Comment: take a look at this project: https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera
It implements almost every aspect of camera2

Comment: @Reyske I have this problem now too. Can you give me please a link to file with code. Because I use xamarin and don't know java project. Thanks